# Protect Spreadsheet worksheet using PHP API google doc

Tags: php, excel, google-api-php-client, worksheet

I have done almost all the things.Last point is remaining, please help me in this.

I have google doc spreadsheet and in that spreadsheet there are 5 sheets.I want to protect 3 of the sheets out of them using **PHP API** I searched over the google but there is no example of PHP.

I can just see [javascript document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setSheetProtection%28PageProtection%29).

I also searched for Class Spreadsheet in PHP SDK but there is no file of this.

Please help me guys.It's last point of my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way to do this is to create a GAS script attached to your spreadsheet and deploy it as a web app. Then you can make GET requests from your PHP script via cURL or whatever else you want to use, like this:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/[your web app token]/exec?sheet=Sheet1&protect=true;
```

In your GAS script, you'll have a doGet() function that looks something like this (not tested):

```
doGet(e){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[your spreadsheet token]");

   try{
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.sheet);
      var permissions = sheet.getSheetProtection();

      if(e.parameter.protect.toLowerCase() == "true"){
         permissions.setProtected(true);
      }else{
         permissions.setProtected(false);
      }
      sheet.setSheetProtection(permissions);
   }catch(error){
      Logger.log("Sheet not found: " + error);
   }
}
```

Of course, you'll probably want to add more robust error handling, but that should get you started.

Comment: Sorry Brother but I did not get what you are trying to tell.Actually I do not have any idea of GAS script at all.The code you have written is in which code? I have access token using PHP.I used google-client library to authenticate and set access token using PHP.Now how to use your code.Any help means a lot to me.

Comment: Take a look at the Google Apps Script tutorials. It's pretty simple once you dive in--plus, I gave a solution that should work with a little copying and pasting: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles

Comment: thanks for the response brother but I have already done so many things with PHP google doc API like created a copy of spreadsheet then via api made it public on web then published it via api and showing that created copy on my website.Now I just only want to hide my formulas from the sheets of spreadsheet. Please help me via PHP.Is there any php example to do that.

Comment: You tagged your question with "google-apps-script", so I thought you were open to using GAS... Are you using a PHP library?

Comment: Please post a link to which one. There are multiple ways to interact with Google Sheets through PHP.

Comment: For example I used this way to create a copy of spreadsheet using PHP https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy#try-it